# Where can I found QT 5.3.0 command prompt

Tags: qt, command-prompt

For studying the Qt book *"C++-gui-programming-with-qt-4-2ndedition"* I need command prompt of Qt. I've installed Qt 5.3.0 (creator 5.3.0 open source) but don't know where is its command prompt.
Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: What "command prompt" do you want exactly ? There is no generic command prompt in Creator. There is the QML console for QML/JS debugging.

Comment: I don't know exactly. But the book says, from a command prompt .....

Comment: This means from `cmd` on Windows, or from a terminal on Linux.

Comment: But there should be a command prompt specific for Qt 5.3.0 apart from the Windows' one.

Comment: Why ? What command are you trying to execute ? (note: I don't use Windows, so perhaps you should edit your question with the *specific* problem you have, to get the attention of someone who does).

Comment: Dear OP. Have you took a look at my answer. This is exactly what you are searching. You want most likely invoke qmake, ui, etc from the terminal. To do that your PATH has to include qt specific folders. Have you tried that?

Comment: Just hit the Windows key and type Qt. It should find you a bunch of different command prompts, for all your installed toolchains. Or just find them in the Start menu under Qt (at least on <=Win7).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you are seeking is a command prompt with an already setup environment (setting PATH variables for a certain Qt kit).
You can find the appropriate batch file in `QTINSTALLPATH/YOURKIT/bin/qtenv2.bat`.
You can e.g. start this batch inside your command shell.

This assumes that your are using a Windows install !

Please be aware that this only sets the environment for Qt ... not your compiler toolchain.

Comment: I'm using Win 7. The book says: _From a command prompt change the directory to "MyProjectName" and then type: Qmake -project_. I could to find that file in this path _C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\mingw482_32\bin_. But what to do with that? Inside my command shell!? What is that? Sorry I'm so novice on _Qt_! PS: I've also installed _Qt VS2012_ on D:\ drive.

Comment: Ok ... i highly recommend that you take a look at the tutorial section of http://qt-project.org. I do not use the mingw kit but i will give you a brief step by step instruction in a few minutes when i got a coffee :-)

Comment: You need to start the command prompt with `cmd`. Now change the directory to `C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\mingw482_32\bin` (i assume from your comments that this is your path. Now call the `qtenv2.bat`. This will setup your path (including your mingw compiler chain path if you installed it along with Qt). Now change to your project folder and try if you can call `qmake` and `g++`. Don't mix mingw and MVSC (visual studio compiler). These are totally different compilers and toolchains. Qt comes precompiled with different kits for different compilers. Choose the one you like (mingw or VS).

Comment: And just as a tip: I assume you are new to c++ programming, since you does not seem to understand the idea of compiler tool chains and so on. You should educate yourself first about the command line (that is pretty awful on Win using `cmd` - but this might be a matter of taste). Then choose a compiler tool chain (mingw of e.g. the MS solution). Make yourself familiar with setting up your environment (command line and IDE). Now - and this is the most important part - learn to program in c++. Without basic c++ knowledge you will never understand the concepts of the Qt framework.